# What is the Pythonic way to "configure" a module?

Tags: python, configuration

I have a Flask application that has modules used to serve as a service layer for the business logic. One of those is a users module. This module interacts with several backend data sources, such as MongoDB, OpenStack Keystone, etc.

I'm curious what the most "Pythonic" way of managing the configuration of these kinds of modules is. In C, for instance, it's common to create a "context" and then pass that around to the various functions. If you want to connect to a different database, then you just create a new context and pass that to the next function.

As an example...

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    MONGODB_URL = '127.0.0.1'
    MONGODB_PORT = 27017

def mongodb_connect():
    return MongoClient(
        BaseConfig.MONGODB_URL,
        BaseConfig.MONGODB_PORT
    )

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.mongodb_client = mongodb_connect()

        self.mongo_doc = self.mongo_client.auth.users.find_one({'id': self.user_id})
        self.email = self.mongo_doc['email']
        self.fname = self.mongo_doc['fname']
        self.lname = self.mongo_doc['lname']

        self.mongodb_client.close()
```

This design doesn't allow for much in the way of flexibility. If you want to get a "user" from a database other than one hosted at `'127.0.0.1'`, you're left with no choice but to update the `BaseConfig` class. Also, adding an argument to the `User` class doesn't seem right because...

```
current_user = User('1234', database_ip='192.168.0.5')
```

...doesn't "feel" right. Why does a `User` class need to know the database IP?

I'm aware of things like ConfigParser and such, but the same basic issue comes across in that there is a configuration "object" you're referencing. I just want to make sure this is the accepted way to solve this problem, and what other alternatives there are.

Comment: In the context of Flask - did you read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/? Flask's app config nicely deals with production vs. local development vs. testing configuration differences, and is trivial to extend for your own purposes or by Flask add-ons.

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes, but Flask isn't the only context that this module will run in. The hope is that this module can be used outside of Flask for non-HTTP/S implementations, for instance behind a zeromq socket.

Comment: I see. "It depends" is the answer then, I'm afraid. There is no silver-bullet or otherwise immediately obvious mechanism that's being used by everyone in the Python ecosystem. People use everything from command line arguments, `.py` / `.ini` / `.yaml` / `.json` config files, environment variables, ... that usually get turned into some sort of config object that gets passed around. It all depends on your use cases and also quite a bit on how your application and/or library is being deployed.

Comment: @LukasGraf Right, I get that. And, I'd like for the "application" itself to be flexible and support some default settings, an `.ini`, as well as command line arguments. I can get that working because I've done in in a few of our microservices. The question I have isn't related to the application's configuration, however. I just want to know how to propagate a setting/config value to a module. So that the module isn't dependent on the overall structure of an application. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: However, one standardized and substantially different approach to those are [`setuptools` entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html?highlight=entry#entry-points). These allow your "package" (technically a setuptools distribution) to create an entry point that other plugin-type packages can use to advertise themselves, and allow for dynamic discovery of additional functionality or configuration. It's basically a form of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Maybe that's something that could be useful for you.

Comment: @LukasGraf Hm, interesting. I hadn't heard of using entry points. I'll have to read into that. Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm starting to get what you're after: You're looking for a way to abstract the subset of the overall configuration that is relevant for a particular module (as in `.py` file), so its particulars can be configured in a way that isn't dependent on the way the whole project / application configuration is managed (e.g. Flask-style config dicts)?

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I want to be able to write a module that is application independent in which I can I can configure specific variables (database IP/URLs, API IP/URLs, etc.) that aren't dependent on a specific application structure. I could handle this if I used a "client" model, i.e., I configure a "client" and then interact with resources through their managers, but that feels wrong.  In C, I would "init" a module and use a context variable, or I would use compile-time constants (#define) to do this work.

Comment: That sounds like you're intending to re-use a `.py` module as-is in a different project / application. In C (which I barely know), I believe it's common to e.g. share `.so` files - but in Python, code reuse doesn't really happen on that level. If you want your module to be reusable (even just by yourself), you often package it up in a setuptools distribution. Unless the code in that `.py` module is being used from multiple places in the same project of course.

Comment: So a module in Python has a much more loosely defined interface than what I understand the relationship between `.c` and their `.h` header files to be. It's really just a way to organize your code on the file system, nothing more. Each module has a global scope, and code in the global scope gets executed the first time the module is imported, allowing for some initialization, but that's about it - other than that it's really just a container for your classes, functions and other module global objects.

Comment: So I'd say you're on the right track with your "client" model - what I often end up doing is to configure objects that hold a global configuration state, like clients, sessions (HTTP sessions, DB sessions) upon module init, by passing them some sort of reference to an "environmental config" (an `argparse` `Options` object, `os.env`, a parsed JSON file). Those classes use keyword arguments for sane defaults, and configure the rest of themselves based on the input from the env config.